# VBA Select just the first visible row

Tags: vba, excel

I know using Select is bad.

I'm trying to select cells from only the first row when multiple results are returned after autofiltering. I've used `xlCellTypeVisible` to copy all of the visible rows, but I'm unsure of how I could make this select cells in the C and D columns in the first filtered row. I would be taking values from the second autofilter before the activecellOffset lines.

```
For i = 2 To k
    Sheets("Database").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C" & k).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        Worksheets("SoPhiH").Range("A" & i).Value, Operator:=xlAnd
    Sheets("Database").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$R" & k).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
        Worksheets("SoPhiH").Range("C" & i).Value, Operator:=xlAnd
    Sheets("Database").Select
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(3, Range("A2:A" & k)) Then ' If the cell is blank copy and paste, else do nothing
    Else
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C" & k).AutoFilter Field:=2
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C" & k).AutoFilter Field:=5

    Sheets("SoPhiH").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Database").Select
    Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    UWI = ActiveCell.Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C" & k).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        UWI, Operator:=xlAnd

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = Worksheets("SoPhiH").Range("C" & i)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17) = Worksheets("SoPhiH").Range("B" & i)
    End If

    Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the same methods used to manipulate a conventional range can be used on the range created by specialcells.

```
with ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C" & k)
    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=UWI
    with .offset(1, 0)
        .specialcells(xlcelltypevisible).offset(0, 2).resize(1, 2).select
    end with
end with
```

If you are dealing with more than the first row, the Areas property my have to be used.